# How to find element in one of two lists

Tags: c#, list, lambda, find

I can search a list, I was using this:

```
if (!mylist.Any(item => item.Thing == searchitem))
    {
        var myvar = mylist.Find(item => item.Thing == searchitem);
    }
```

However, there's a scenario where I can't find the item. And in that case I want to search another list. I'd like to do something like the following but get an error (var myvar triggers: implicitly typed variable must be initialized).

```
var myvar;
if (!mylist.Any(item => item.Thing == searchitem))
{
    myvar = mylist.Find(item => item.Thing == searchitem);
}
else
{
    myvar = mylist.Find(item => item.Thing == searchitem);
}
mystring = myvar.Thing;
```

I'm open to another structure of list.Find for achieving the same result but I really want to use myvar further in my code and not have two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scan `myList` *twice*: first in `Any` then in `Find`. You can try `FirstOrDefault` instead:

```
// Either found item or null (assuming that item is class)
var myvar = myList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Thing == searchitem);
```

If you have *two* lists you can check if you get default value and start scanning `list2` in this case:

```
var myvar = myList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Thing == searchitem) ??
            myList2.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Thing == searchitem);

if (myvar != null) {
  // if myvar has been found in either myList or myList2
  mystring = myvar.Thing;
  ...
}
```

Finally, in *general case* if you have several lists, you can organize them into a collection `myLists` and *flatten* it with a help of `SelectMany`:

```
var myLists = new List<MyType>[] {
  myList,
  myList2,
  myList3,
  // ... etc.
};

var myvar = myLists
  .SelectMany(list => list)
  .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Thing == searchitem);
```

**Edit:** If `list` and `list2` are of *different type* then you should come to common base type, e.g.

```
// I've used `object` as a common type; but you'd rather use
// a more specific one 
object myvar = 
  (myList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Thing == searchitem) as object) ??
   myList2.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Thing == searchitem);
```

Comment: thanks, this seems like a great solution. However, when I try the second option, I get:

Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Form1.FirstList' and 'Form1.SecondList'

Do the lists need the same elements?

Also for the third option, if the two lists have different elements do I need to create a class with all the elements and that is what would be MyType?

Comment: Yes, if you use `var` both lists should be of the same type: you can't change type on the fly, say "if I haven't found TextBox in list1, let's search for Button in list2". Or at least items within both list should be descenant of the same type, implement same interface...

Comment: @SpaghettiWestern: If you have lists of *different* types, could you, please, *specify* them and what exactly you are going to find - what type should result be?

Comment: Yes, they are different types. The common element is the ID. So I want to search for ID (a string) and if it's not found in one list, then I want to use the second list as the source of data further in the code. The other elements include int and double.

Comment: SpaghettiWestern: OK; so if item is found in `list` then `myvar` should be of, say `MyType1` and if in the item is found in `list2` then `myvar` will be of `MyType2`? Technically, you can declare `myvar` as `dynamic`, but do you really want `myvar`
to be of *different type* depending on search result?

Comment: Yes that's right. Based on your answer, I optimized my code no longer need to go down this alternate path with different lists. I will mark your answer correct, thanks for providing a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `var` without initialization, because a compiler does not know what type it is. Just change to explicit type of your list element type.

For example you have `List<int>` so your variable should be `int myvar`.

Comment: Thanks @Xeo. I did do some testing with that, so I should add that the list type is different for each list - e.g. one is public class MyStuff and the other is public class TheirStuff. So I'm unsure how to account for both scenarios with one variable.

Comment: Are classes related by inheriting? If yes, you can use base type, if not, you can use just `object` as variable type, but then you need to cast object as you access a concrete property - `myvar.Thing`.  The better solution would be declare variable of `Thing` property type and store only `Thing` object instead of whole list element. You can assign it inside your if statement, but use `SingleOrDefault(x => ...)?.Thing` instead of `Find`.